# Android: Button selector is not working in disabled state

Tags: android, android-layout

I have `Button` selector I'm using in multiple projects and its working perfectly is not working with brand new project for some reason. I can't figure it out why it is happening.

**button_main**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="200dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/button_main_selector" />
</shape>
```

**button_main_selector**

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:exitFadeDuration="200"
    android:enterFadeDuration="200">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:color="@color/main_color"
        />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:color="@color/main_color"
        />
    <item
        android:alpha="1"
        android:color="@color/main_color"/>
</selector>
```

**style**

```
 <style name="MainButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_main</item>
 </style>
```

**App theme**

```
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"
```

Enabled color is correct but disabled color is dark grey in dark mode and white in light mode (I cant see button if its disabled on screen)